# Fixing "How to check Oracle database for long running queries"

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

The question *"[How to check Oracle database for long running queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/622289/how-to-check-oracle-database-for-long-running-queries)"* was closed as "Not a Real Question".

The question seems pretty good to me. The asker has an application running against Oracle and they are wondering which queries are slow to execute.

I can't see which of these apply to the question "ambiguous, vague, incomplete, overly broad, or rhetorical".

What needs to be fixed to make this a real question?

Comment: It is not fixable.  Deleting it is best, I doubt that will break the Internet since it isn't anywhere close in the Google results for the natural search "oracle query optimization"..

Comment: It does have nearly 175,000 views - an average of 100 per day over its life so far.

Comment: The question isn't how to optimise a query, it's how do I find a long running query?  You need to do this to figure out what needs to optimised.

Comment: Gave it an edit to make it better, and a re-open vote because I don't see any reason for it being closed. Or staying closed.

Answer (score -3):

There are several different ways of locating long running queries. Note that just because a query runs a long time does not automatically mean it needs tuning. You have to look and see what the query is doing. That is in some cases a long running query has to do a lot of work.

---

If the site has the EM Diagnostic Pack license run an AWR report and review the section on the top SQL by CPU, Elapsed Time, etc....

---

If no EM Diagnostic Pack license you can set up and run Statspack.

---

The view V$SESSION_LONGOPS will show all sessions currently running a "long" running query.  what constitutes a LONG running query is subject to debate.

---

You can query V$SESSION where the STATIS is ACTIVE and the LAST_CALL_ET is > the number of seconds you consider long running to the SQL_ID for long running SQL and/or join to V$SQL to see statement.

---

You can get the plan for long running SQL from V$SQL_PLAN (use DBMS_XPLAN).

Comment: Questions on meta about questions on main are not meant to receive an answer that should be posted on the actual question on the main site. This is a very meta comment.

Comment: So you need to write an answer to *What needs to be fixed to make this a real question?* and that advice then needs to be applied to the question on main so the text you posted currently here can go on that question on main.

Comment: For less confusion see https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta